# automatic dataframe names

Tags: r, dataset

I have around 100 dataframes with same structure, like `d1`, `d2` ,`d3`, ..., `d10`, `d11`, ..., `d100`. I have to `rbind` them together, like `rbind(d1,d2,.....dxx)`.

I don't want to manually write all dataframes names because in that case I have manually write more than 100 dataframe names and that number could increase in future. can you please help write an automatic way to `rbind(d1,d2,d3,...,d10, d11,.....,d100,....)`?

Answer (score 2):

First create a character vector of all objects that you want to bind, like:

```
NameDf <- paste("d", 1:100, sep = "")
```

Now, first call each object using `get` function and bind them together using `do.call`

```
NewDf <- do.call(cbind, lapply(NamesDf, FUN = function(x) get(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mget` to return a `list` of values

```
out <- do.call(rbind, mget(paste0("d", 1:100)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on akrun's elegant answer (using `mget()`), but using `dplyr`'s efficient `bind` implementation to avoid the `do.call()`:

```
library(dplyr)
mget(paste0("d",1:100)) %>% bind_rows()
```

Answer (score -1):

Example - from my work:

```
filename_vector <- paste0(i, sep="_", df$unique.label.within.df, 
                          sep="", "intended.filename.csv")
```